# missing type in Java Eclipse

Tags: java

For my NSF REU, I am trying to use SourceAFIS, the open source Java library for fingerprint recognition.  In Eclipse, I get the error that a method in my `FingerprintMatcher` class "refers to the missing type `TIntObjectHashMap`".

However, `TIntObjectHashMap.java` is in the same project, under the path `/SourceAFIS/generated-src/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntObjectHashMap.java`.

At the top of TIntObjectHashMap.java I have: 
package gnu.trove.map.hash;

At the top of `FingerprintMatcher`.java I have:

```
import gnu.trove.map.hash.*;
```

I do not know what is causing the problem and appreciate the help.

Comment: Make sure the folder where TIntObjectHashMap.java is located is considered as a source folder by Eclipse. (Has a little package icon)
If it's not, follow the instructions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_set_src_fold.htm)

Comment: Also, if everything *looks* correct to you, you can try and clean your project. Eclipse can be confused at times `Project > Clean`